# Reading a File while it is being written by FFMPEG

Tags: java, php, ffmpeg

As the title suggests, i am in the process of creating a client/server application where the server(PHP) reads a file which is being written on by ffmpeg and then outputs it to the client(JAVA). I have succeeded in writing the server script in php which initiates the ffmpeg and then after a while starts to read the file and concurrently sends it to the JAVA client, the problem is that after a while the client stops to receive any sort of data and then just quits, For example if i have a 5MB file, it would read only 12KB and then it quits. Could someone tell what can be the issue here? Is it on the server side or on the client side. 
For References i am attaching both the reading of file code in php and the client side code.

Code For Reading the file while FFMPEG converts the file(PHP):

```
$file = 'D:\\'.$destination;
$fp = @fopen($file, 'r');
//ob_end_clean();  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

$buffer = 4096;
while(!feof($fp)) {

usleep(300000);
echo fread($fp, $buffer);
ob_flush();
flush();


}
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Code For reading the File transferred by PHP (JAVA):

```
URL u = new URL(streamURL);

                clientSocket = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

                if( clientSocket.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
                //clientSocket.setReadTimeout(0);
                inRemoteStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();


                while (((count = inRemoteStream.read(buf)) != -1)) {
                    offset += count;
                    System.out.println(offset);
                    fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, count);
                    setVideoOffset(offset, contentLength);
                }
```

I`ll be very happy if someone can solve this problem for me :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back again. This can not be technically interpreted as an answer but merely a different logic to accomplish this task i posted so i can safely say that this can be the answer(soft of) :) . 
         What i did was instead of reading the file while it is being written upon, i started the ffmpeg shell exec command with the 'run in background' option and read the file AFTER ffmpeg converted the file, the results were accurate for small files like 4MB but i instantly ran into another problem when i started converting and reading files more than 30MB . After some in depth research i got to know that when i was converting a 30MB or above file using ffmpeg what happened was after the conversion, the php script was not giving back its control to JAVA applet in order for it to read the stream, so what i did was that i inserted a simple 'http_response_code(200)' after ffmpeg finished converting and saving the file and voila it works. For references here is what i did in PHP:

```
http_response_code(200);  
$file = 'D:\\'.$destination;
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
//ob_end_clean();  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
//header("Cache-control: private");
//header('Pragma: private');
//header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

$buffer = 1024*8;
while(!feof($fp)) {

echo fread($fp, $buffer);
ob_flush();
flush();



}
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Hope it helps anyone who is stuck in a similar problem.

Regards
Haris Tasawar.